# Sending variables to bash from python

Tags: python, linux, bash, debian, wifi

I have tried my best to research and I have got to the point where I am using subprocess and subprocess.call to help me send my python variables to bash. I managed to get my python variables from bash output but now I need these variables to be in sync. I looked around couldn't learn how to use subprocess.call effectively. I have been using subprocess.check_output to obtain bash output into python variables flawlessly. I am having troubles understand how subprocess.call accepts arguments and how to use it properly. I tried following what I believed to be the correct format. 
Here is my code. P.S I am brand new to joining this forum although I have been using it for tons of usefull information over the years. I dont know how to format my code input to look nice like how I see all over here. Regardless im sure you can forgive me as I tried the "Code" "Blockquotes" etc buttons.

```
###BEGINING OF CODE###
#! /usr/bin/env python2
import os,time,subprocess

#GRAB DATA
os.system('ifconfig > /tmp/ifconfig.txt;clear;cat /tmp/ifconfig.txt|grep "wlan"|cut -c 1-5 > /tmp/dev.lst;clear;')

#SET allwlan
allwlan=subprocess.check_output("cat /tmp/dev.lst", shell=True)

#SET max_index VARIABLE
max_index=subprocess.check_output("wc -l < /tmp/dev.lst", shell=True)

#SET curwlan WLAN LINE
#os.system(echo 2 > /tmp/curline.lst)

#STRIP DATA FOR curwlan
subprocess.call(['head', '-2', '/tmp/dev.lst', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True'])
#NEED#HELP#HERE# subprocess.call(['tail', '-1', > /tmp/curwlan.lst;')

#SET curwlan VARIABLE
curwlan=subprocess.check_output("cat /tmp/curwlan.lst", shell=True)

##STRIP EXCESS  CHARACTERS/EMPTY LINES FROM VARIABLES##
curwlan=str(curwlan)
splitted=curwlan.split()
curwlan=splitted[0]
allwlan=allwlan[:-1]
splitted=max_index.split()
max_ index=splitted[0]
max_index=int(max_index)

##DEBUG MODE
print("Welcome, ")
print("     to debug mode. wireless adapter decting algorithm")
print
print("ALLWLAN:")
print(allwlan)
print
print("CURWLAN:")
print(curwlan)
print
print("MAX_INDEX:")
print(max_index)
print
input("PRESS ENTER TO EXIT")
####END OF CODE####*
```

The error in my code is under
    #STRIP DATA FOR curwlan

Here is the output of that before I added the subprocess.call command.

```
Welcome, 
    to debug mode. wireless adapter decting algorithm

ALLWLAN:
wlan0
wlan3

CURWLAN:
wlan2

MAX_INDEX:
2

PRESS ENTER TO EXIT
```

I would love to learn how to have my python and bash parts communicate their variables together and I know I am on the right track with subprocess.call and ive been struggling for a few days now. I am trying to make my own algorithm to detect my wireless cards and be able to use each one (how ever many that may be or regardless what they may be named) as a variable for my 
older scripts which now are struggling because of my constantly changing wireless card names. Thanks in advance I don't understand if what i'm asking subprocess.call to do is unrealistic or not.

Comment: I simply print stuff in my python script and in my bash script I do `someVar=$(python script.py)$

Comment: Your `tail` command does nothing without any input file. From which file or stream are you attempting to extract the last line?

Comment: You cannot have a `###BEGINNING OF CODE###` comment before the shebang line; it needs to be absolutely the first thing in the script file.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to avoid external processes as much as possible.  Most of what you are doing is easy to do in just Python, and will be much more compact as well as more efficient if implemented natively.

Also, you are mixing the obsolete `os.system()` with `subprocess` where the latter is generally to be preferred, as also pointed out in the `os.system()` documentation.

`subprocess.call()` is only really appropriate when you don't expect any output from a command.  The instance where you tried to use it, `subprocess.check_output()` would be the proper call to use.  However, the places where you (as I understand, needlessly) ran shell commands with output to temporary files, you could have used `subprocess.call()`, trivially.

You need to understand when and where a shell is useful and necessary.  Many places where you have `shell=True` would be more secure, faster, simpler, and more straightforward without a shell.  Where you only run a simple hard-coded command with no redirection or globbing, switching from `subprocess.whatever('command with args', shell=True)` to `subprocess.whatever(['command', 'with', 'args'])` will instantly reduce your time and memory footprint with no ill effects.  If you need redirection, pipelines, or globbing, *maybe* you want `shell=True`; but in many cases, doing those things in Python will be simple and straightforward.  For example, here is how the `head` command could have been written without a shell:

```
with open('/tmp/randomfile', 'w') as outputfile:
    subprocess.call(['head', '-n', '2', '/tmp/dev.lst'], stdout=outputfile)
```

Anyway, with these things out of the way, here is how I would do what (I think) you are attempting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import subprocess

allwlan = []
ifconfig = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig'])
for line in ifconfig.split('\n'):
    if "wlan" in line:
        allwlan.append(line[0:5].strip())

max_index=len(allwlan)
curwlan=allwlan[1]
```

This was hastily thrown together, but I believe I captured at least most of what your current pretzel logic code does; though I have assumed that sprinkling the `/tmp` file system with random output files was not an essential feature of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advice. My script has come along way; Here is what this part looks like, over 1 year later,

```
def detmon():
try:
    subprocess.call(['clear'])      
    item = []
    items = []
    the_choice = []

    iwconfig = subprocess.check_output(['iwconfig'])
    for line in iwconfig.split():
     if "mon" in line:
      items.append(line.strip(':'))
    subprocess.call(['clear'])
    max_index=len(items)-1
    #items=items[counter]

    #Print Files List
    for item in items:
        print(" ", items.index(item), ": ", item)
    os.system('echo "\n"')
    print(len(items))
    try:
        if len(items) >= 0: 
            counter = 0
            allmon = []
            ifconfig = subprocess.check_output(['iwconfig'])
            for line in ifconfig.split():
             if "mon" in line:
              allmon.append(line.strip(':'))
            subprocess.call(['clear'])
            max_index=len(allmon)
            curmon=allmon[counter]
            while counter <= max_index:
             curmon=allmon[counter]
             subprocess.call(['airmon-ng', 'stop', curmon])
             counter += 1
        else:
                print("No more 'mon' interfaces are found")
    except:     
            print("No more 'mon' interfaces are found")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```